# how to open popup window using adf faces

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, oracle-adf

How to open a popup using adf faces? I am using adf-faces-api-10_1_3_0_4.jar and adf-faces-impl-10_1_3_0_4.jar files for UI.

Answer (score 1):

In JDeveloper 10.1.3 (or ADF Faces 10.1.3) there is not specific popup component. You can open a window by navigating to a navigation case name with the prefix of "dialog:". For example, dialog:name would open the view in a dialog window that has a navigation case of dialog:name specified. The "dialog:" indicates to the ADF Faces dialog framework to open a modal window. You can configure a return listener on the calling command item (the one that has dialog:name in its action property) so you can handle return values.

Here_s a sample: [Show lookup details in popup (dialog) window using ADF Faces & JHeadstart 10.1.3](http://technology.amis.nl/2006/07/25/show-lookup-details-in-popup-dialog-window-using-adf-faces-jheadstart-1013/)

Frank